# How do I format general data type to date format?

Tags: worksheet-function, excel-2016

I have a general formatted column with dates written as 'Jan 17'. I tried to highlight the column and change the category to a couple different date formats and nothing happens. I tried custom and different date formats as well as manually using mmyy, none work. I am building a dashboard in Tableau and I need the data in a date format otherwise the measure is not calculated correctly.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, the dates are formatted this way: 'Jan 17' and you want them formatted as 'January 2017'?

Comment: I want to change the formatting from a string to a date but the basic formatting function does not do this.

Comment: If this is a one time thing would it be easier to just find and replace, and then change the formatting after? So find "Jan 17" replace "January 2017"?

Comment: A find and replace does not convert my field from a string to a date format.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Sub ChangeFormat()
Columns("C:C").Select 'your range here
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
End Sub
```